# What purpose do these airbrush accessories serve and how does their use\effect differ?

Tags: tool-usage, airbrush

What is the difference between these airbrush accessories in terms of how they would be used and the effect that they produce when spraying.

Numbered 1 to 7 from top left to bottom right.

I'm looking for an answer from an artistic source (for example a trade review or an unboxing video with demonstrations), which goes beyond the product description on the retailers website.  I'm specifically looking for information that is NOT included in the source link, not a cut and paste of the manufacturer's original description as these can be extremely unreliable.

[image: Airbrush accessories]

[Source](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003229255949.html?gatewayAdapt=4itemAdapt)

Comment: @– fixer1234 I specifically don't want people to answer based on that source.

Comment: With the clarification in the question about what you're looking for in an answer, and the comment above, I think you're safe.  :-)

Comment: It would be nice if someone simply had a video showing them in action and explaining that X accessory modifies the spray in X way, something that can be demonstrated so that the answer does not get deleted as being "Opinion Based". Or simply a text explanation of the above.

Answer (score 3):

First those are *not* airbrush nozzles. They are "Airbrush Cover Assories".

They claim to be guides to assist in creating specific effects like a specific line weight or soft cover. Not sure how that would work since anything dragging against the support will damage whatever paint has gone down. Also they would collect overspray and create drops and smears.

Here are the official descriptions from the [AliExpress website](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/3256803042941197.html?gatewayAdapt=4itemAdapt) item with that image (edited only for layout, spelling errors are theirs):

NT-1: Long distance, large area, large angle

NT-2: Efficient disperse airflow at close-range operation, and makes the-edge of color lump more smooth, and reduce the paint accumulation.

NT-3: Close range, large area, large angle, and reduce the paint accumulation.

NT-4: Medium distance, large area, large angle,and
protect needle, make the airbrush plays a finest performance with fewer restrictions of spary scope.(it can work with o-ring to adjust the tightning locked position)

NT-6: help collecting airflow, reducing the spary scope of airbrush, hollow out structure design can ensures the smooth airflow, suitable for painting shadow and thin lines in small area.

NT-7: press against the surface of item to spary it, suitable for
painting lines of uniform thickness: large hollow out design can
reduce the paint accumulation, and with unrestricted spray scope,
freely control the spray effect.(it can work with o-ring to adjust
the tightning locked position)

**But frankly they do nothing to change the spray pattern. That comes from the nozzle, needle set, airflow, and how you handle the brush. These items are window dressing at best. If they were to actually block the airflow like they describe it would just make a mess.**

(edit: a user suggested there may be a niche application for these tips. If so hopefully someone with experience in that area could fill in the blank.)

Comment: I'm not asking for a manufacturer's description of a product, I'm asking for what effect using each of them has on paint flow. If you need to do a reverse image lookup then you probably don't know what they are and are just giving a cut and paste answer.

Comment: @AaarghZombies, a lot of manufacturers create fancy-looking accessories that don't really do anytyhing special or have a practical use.  They aren't necessarily a standard or scientific design or have an obvious function, if they actually do anything useful. The manufacturer's claimed function/purpose may be the only clue as to their intended use.

Comment: I would argue that a potentially mistranslated product description from a random internet seller could be misleading at best, and copied and pasted form an entirely different product at worst.

Comment: @fixer1234 Can you put a source to that claim? For example, are you aware of an airbrush unboxer with a video demonstrating it?

Comment: @AaarghZombies, I'm not claiming that this specific product is a scam (don't know for certain). My point was that many aftermarket accessories don't really do anything, and the question wording seems to assume that these work as intended. These could be designed to do something useful (what the manufacturer describes), and be effective at that, or they could serve no useful function and even produce unwanted artifacts in the process. #1 might control overspray, but it doesn't look like most of the rest would actually do anything useful, especially as described by the manufacturer. (cont'd)

Comment: The shapes might selectively block a little overspray and produce an unwanted pattern, but they aren't likely to affect the airflow as the manufacturer suggests, and they could accumulate paint, producing some splatter. If these were standard accessories in common use, you're right that people who have experience using them could describe the effects. But if most airbrush users have no need to try them, what the manufacturer claims they do is a baseline. (cont'd)

Comment: People would have a hard time guessing what an odd shape is supposed to do, but can assess whether there is merit to what the manufacturer claims is its purpose. Is your real question what are these supposed to do and do they work as intended ("how they would be used" refers to usage as designed), or what is the shape of any artifact pattern they happen to produce? If the latter, "how they would be used" could include anything, including using them as paperweights.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Harder & Steenbeck Infinity (and a couple of other) airbrushes. Most nozzle and needle sets I own for the Infinity came with either a nozzle cap like #3, #4 or #6.

As far as I know #4 should be used as a spacer to be able to spray thin lines evenly, which doesn't work very well and you get better results freehand with a little bit of practice.
#3/6 should be used as a needle protection for when working very close to the subject.
To my knowledge, they do not alter the spray pattern. The other shown caps just look like variations from #3 or #6 and I can not imagine them altering the spray pattern either, although I cant be sure.

The most efficient way to control your spray pattern is to use different needles and nozzles (beside the obvious: distance to subject, airflow and needle control).